# Replace "The post could not be loaded" by a more informative error message when trying to edit one's deleted question

Tags: feature-request, edits, wording, error-message, deleted-posts

When trying to edit a question that one deleted earlier, one receives the error message "The post could not be loaded", as illustrated below. I'd suggest to replace it by a more informative error message, e.g. "Deleted questions cannot be edited".

[image]

[image]

Comment: -1, not enough freehand circles.